# MVC pattern don't understand one sentence

Tags: model-view-controller, puremvc

Trying to use PureMVC framework and understand MVC concept. Don't understand this sentence:

The Model caches named references to Proxies, which expose an API for manipulating the Data Model.

The View primarily caches named references to Mediators, which adapt and steward the View Components that make up the user interface.

What are cached references, Mediators, Proxies, Command. Tell please. Don't understand. Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like MVC refers to a design pattern, Mediators, Proxies and Command refer to other design patterns.
A [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache) is `a component that transparently stores data so that future requests for that data can be served faster`

There are links to the other patterns mentioned on the [PureMVC wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PureMVC).
[Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)
[Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)
[Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)